# iText PDF MultiColumnText Line Height

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm having trouble setting the line height for a Paragraph object when its added to a Column inside a MultiColumnText object.

Notice the arbitrary spacing between each new line. Screen shot here of rendered content on 2nd column. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/249320/Foliotek/Capture.PNG

I have it rendering and going to the next column correctly. But I cant seem to set the height of each new row. Thoughts?

My Code:

```
MultiColumnText mct = new MultiColumnText();
            mct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL;
            //8

            // setup column 1
            float[] left = {1020, 280, 1020, 7 };
            float[] right = {1022, 576,
                         1022, 280,
                         1096, 280,
                         1214, 154,
                         1214, 7
                        };
            mct.AddColumn(left, right);

            // setup column 2
            left = new float[] { 1422, 576,
                              1422, 266,
                              1259, 106,
                              1246, 105,
                              1246, 7
                             };
            right = new float[] {1433, 280, 1433, 7 };
            mct.AddColumn(left, right);
            techDataColumnText += " GALLIA est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae, nostra Galli appellantur.  Hi omnes lingua, institutis, legibus inter se differunt. Gallos ab Aquitanis Garumna flumen, a Belgis Matrona et Sequana dividit. Horum omnium fortissimi sunt Belgae, propterea quod a cultu atque humanitate provinciae longissime absunt, minimeque ad eos mercatores saepe commeant atque ea quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent important, proximique sunt Germanis, qui trans Rhenum incolunt, quibuscum continenter bellum gerunt.  Qua de causa Helvetii quoque reliquos Gallos virtute praecedunt, quod fere cotidianis proeliis cum Germanis contendunt, cum aut suis finibus eos prohibent aut ipsi in eorum finibus bellum gerunt.";
            Paragraph techDataPhrase = new Paragraph(techDataColumnText, new Font(FuturaBoldBaseFont, 8f));

            mct.AddElement(techDataPhrase);
            do
            {
                document.Add(mct);
                mct.NextColumn();
            } while (mct.IsOverflow());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three thoughts:

1. `MultiColumnText` has been removed from the latest iText release, so you may not want to invest much time in it. Use `ColumnText` if you want a future-proof solution.
2. You say that there's an arbitrary line-height. In PDF language the line-height is called the leading. I don't see you using `setLeading()` anywhere (maybe I'm overlooking something).
3. `(Multi)ColumnText` and `PdfPCell` have two different modes. Text mode and composite mode.

In *composite mode*, the settings of the container (the column or the cell) are ignored in favor of the settings of the contents (the `Paragraph` and other objects that are added). In this mode, the contents of the container can have different leadings, alignments,...

In *text mode*, you set the leading at the level of the container (the column or the cell) and all the content follows that setting. In this mode, all the content has the same leading, same alignment,...

You're creating an irregular column, that means that you can only work in *text mode*. You need to set the leading at the level of the column.

Comment: You were right I had to add the leading at the Column Level. Also iText 4 doesn't actually set the leading at the Column Level correctly you must be using iText 5 for it to work correctly with irregular columns. Thank you Bruno